# LV & HV MOSFETs

Tags: transistors

What are some of the differences between low voltage and high voltage MOSFETs? Obviously the voltage rating would be higher for HV transistors but is there anything that would always be true/false about either transistors disregarding internal design parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Switching speeds are generally slower

Gate capacitance (as well as the other capacitance) are generally higher

Stray inductance usually higher.

Thermal capabilities are better

The reverse recovery current of the intrinsic diode is higher

The question is quite vague to give a definitive list.

Comment: Don't forget that the die size increases roughly as the square of the voltage (for the same process) meaning the cost rises dramatically too.(For constant RDSon).